# How do I customise the HTML Filter from Power-Mezz?

Tags: html, filter, rebol, rebol2

I'm experimenting with the [HTML Filter](http://rebol.it/power-mezz/mezz/filter-html.html) module from the [PowerMezz](http://rebol.it/power-mezz/) library and would like to customise the filter rules for a particular instance of the function. Is this possible?

For example, by default the `style` attribute is permitted, however I'd like to have this attribute stripped:

```
>> filter-html {<p style="color:red">A Para</p>}
== {<p>A Para</p>}
```

As well as limiting some other tags/attributes that are otherwise allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After studying the `filter-html` module it looks like the immediate answer is no --- there appears to be no way to change the filter options for a particular instance.

After some experimentation, however, I discovered that you can make small change to make something like this possible. Most attribute handling can be customized by changing the `attributes-map` block, but inline style attributes are not handled in that block. They are dealt with specifically in the `check-attributes` function.

I commented out these lines in `check-attributes` which then causes all style attributes get stripped out by default:

```
if value: select attributes 'style [
        append style value
]
```

You would need to add the ones you didn't want filtered back in to the specific html tags in `attribute-map`. I make a copy of the original `attribute-map`, make my changes, run `filter-html`, then revert back to the original before the next filtering instance.